# Unable to load the images while using a function in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm new to coding and currently working on a project that using webpack. I want to create a menu with 20 items presented in card styles, where each card includes both the item name and its corresponding picture. Notably, the image names match the item names.

I've implemented a function to generate these cards, but I'm encountering an issue where the images fail to load on the page when using the function to call the image names. If I manually type in the photo name, the image successfully loads. Therefore, I'm sure all the photos are imported. I wonder how to address this issue and optimal the process. Thank you.

```
function importAll(r) {
    let images = {};
    r.keys().map((item, index) => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
    return images;
  }
  
  const images = importAll(require.context('./images', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
```

```
const itemList = ["Honey", "Chocolate", "Matcha", "Coffee"];

function cards(e) {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("menu-item");
    const itemName = document.createElement("h2");
    itemName.textContent = e;
    const picture = document.createElement("img");
    picture.src = `images['${e.toLowerCase()}.jpg'];`; // work if I type images[honey.jpg];
    picture.alt = `${e}`;
    card.appendChild(picture);
    card.appendChild(itemName);
    return card
}

function menuPage() {
    const mainContent = document.createElement('div');
    mainContent.classList.add("menuContent");
    const header = document.createElement('h1');
    header.classList.add("header");
    header.textContent="Our Menu";
    mainContent.appendChild(header);

    for (let i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++){
        const e = itemList[i];
        mainContent.appendChild(cards(e));
    }
    return mainContent;
}
```

Comment: What's the type of e? Is it an event object or a string?

Comment: @Odri It is the string in the itemList array.